# Logstash file output to different host

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

Logstash is running on a K8 pod. I'm trying to save logstash data to a file in a different host.

Can you please let me know how to set host name?

```
output {

    file {
        path => "/app/log/path/%{Name}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the `file` output only writes locally, there is no option to set a host.

To use the `file` output to write in another host you would need to export the directory from the target host and mount it in the logstash machine.